# Bash function for 'Deep Replace' in file contents, file name, directory name, allowing for whitespace

Tags: bash, sed

On my Ubuntu system, I commonly need to do a 'Deep Replace' in file contents, the file name and directory name. For example when copying source code as a template for another application.

I've put together a function in `~/.bashrc` which works, but fails if the find or replace string has white space in it. I believe this is due to the **sed** command not accepting white space in the script as is, and the **cd** to the path variable also fails where the path includes white space.

The arguments are ($1) directory, ($2) find text, ($3) replace text.

Is it possible to improve this script so the arguments can all include white space?

```bash
deepreplace() {


    if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ] || [ -z "$3" ]
    then
        echo "A parameter is missing"
    else

        cd $1

        vfind=$2
        vreplace=$3 

        # Replace the string in file

        find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g" {} +

        # Replace the string in file names, then directories


        find . -type d -name "*$vfind*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g"); done
        find . -type f -name "*$vfind*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g"); done
    fi
}
```

Comment: The sed is fine with whitespace, and the cd (which you don't need, by the way) just needs a quoted variable. It's the loop that parses the output of find that needs improvement. What operating system are you using? Do you have GNU find? Does your find have a -print0 or -printf option?

Comment: Also, any args with spaces, tabs, shell metachars in them **must** be quoted (or appropriately escaped) when passed to the script or function.

Comment: @terdon - the cd is to force that the user specifies the directory, to prevent accidental use in the wrong directory. GNU find - is that different to the find command already used in the script? I presume you mean it's the input to mv that is causing problems with spaces?

Comment: The `cd` isn't needed since `find` can take `$1` as the directory to search in, it doesn't need to use `.`: `find "/some/path" -name foo` works fine. As for GNU find, I don't know if it's different :) That's why I asked you to tell us what OS you are using. The default `find` on Linux systems is usually GNU `find`, but macOS and other UNIX systems have different implementations. So either please tell us your OS or check `man find` and see if your `find` has the `-print0` or `-printf` options.

Comment: @terdon - OK thanks, understood on point about cd. Yes, I do have print0, printf available (its Ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: See also: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: How do you want to handle cases where you have more than one matching directory? For example, if `vfind=foo` and `vreplace=bar` and you have a directory called `foo` which is a subdirectory of another called foo (`/whatever/foo/something/foo`). Do we need to be able to handle such cases?

Comment: @terdon, yes that would need to handled. Another good point. At this point I'm thinking this may be better implemented in Python / Node due the complexity. While I'm sure bash can achieve what I'm trying to do here, it feels like it might not be the best tool for the job, at least with my current bash skills.

Comment: You can do things like this in bash, but yeah, it can get quite complicated fast. Proper scripting languages (bash is a shell, not a programming language although it can function as one) will always be better choices as soon as the complexity rises even a little.

Comment: Use find's `-exec` (or `-execdir`) option instead of piping into a shell while-read loop.  If necessary, you can run shell code with `sh -c "...shell code here..." find-sh {} +` from `-exec`, or write a standalone shell script and run that from `find ... -exec`.   If you have the perl rename utility installed, you could run something like `find . -name "*$vfind*" -exec rename "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g" {} +` (this will rename both directories AND regular files).

Answer (score 1):

As in comments, I've determined that a pure bash solution was not optimal for my use case.

I've settled for a command that depends on Node.js / npm (since Node is fairly ubiquitous on environments I work on, including non Unix (Windows / Mac).

It depends on two npm packages [renamer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/renamer) and [replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace).

The advantage of using these libraries is that they support regex and other more advanced rename / replace scenarios.

With Node.js / npm installed:

```bash
# Globally install the required packages (this prevents npx from trying to install in current directory if they do not already exist)

$ npm install -g renamer
$ npm install -g replace

# Set variables (dir, find, replace) for directory, find and replace strings, then run change directory, rename and replace, before reverting to original directory.
# npx is not strictly required, but have included to prevent collisions with command names on the PATH.

$ dir="./example_dir" && 
   find="example_find" && 
     replace="example_replace" && 
       cd "$dir" && 
        npx renamer --find "$find" --replace "$replace" "**" && 
            npx replace "$find" "$replace" . -r 
                && cd -
```

The equivalent .bashrc function looks like this

```bash
renamereplace() {

    # Install global packages if not installed

    npm list -g renamer || npm install -g renamer
    npm list -g replace || npm install -g replace

    # Alias positional arguments

    dir="$1"
    find="$2"
    replace="$3" 

    # Change to replace directory

    cd "$dir"

    # Rename in directory and file names

    npx renamer --find "$find" --replace "$replace" "**" 

    # Replace in file contents

    npx replace "$find" "$replace" . -r 

    # Revert current directory

    cd -
}
```

And can be called with:

```bash
$ renamereplace "./example_dir" "example_find" "example_replace"
```

**Disclaimer: To avoid data loss, ensure you a) understand this script, b) have checked the directory this command will run in and c) have backed up any important data before running the above.**

Comment: Your original version would have also choked on whitespace, which is why I edited to add the quotes. You should _always_ quote your variables to avoid this.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your help and input

Answer (score 0):

Your function were almost conform to your requirements, just missing a lot of quotes around variables and substitutions, that's why it did not resist to space in filenames.

- variables : "$1" "$2" "$f" etc.
- substitutions : "$( ... )"

Here is a first low touch review:

```
deepreplace() {
  if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ] || [ -z "$3" ]
  then
      echo "A parameter is missing"
  else
    cd "$1" # quote missing
    vfind="$2" # quote missing
    vreplace="$3" # quote missing
    # Replace the string in file contents
    find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g" {} +
    # Replace the string in directory names
    find . -type d -name "*$vfind*" |
    while read d ; do
      mv "$d" "$(echo "$d" | sed "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g")"
    done
    # Replace the string in file names
    find . -type f -name "*$vfind*" |
    while read f; do
      mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g")"
    done
  fi
}
```

next improvements:

- instead of `$(echo $v | sed s/x/y/g)` use the built-in `${v//x/y}`
  example: `mv "$f" "${f//$vfind/$vreplace}"`
- you have a problem when the path is to be replaced at more than directory level; that's why you first target directories then files (and not files then directories)
- it's useless to perform `find` three times

Here is a pure bash new approach:

```
    find . | while read p ; do
      ddir="$(dirname "${p//$vfind/$vreplace}")"
      obas="$(basename "$p")"
      nbas="${obas//$vfind/$vreplace}"
      # if object rename
      [[ $obas != $nbas ]] && mv "$ddir/$obas" "$ddir/$nbas"
      # if object is file, edit
      [ -f "$ddir/$nbas" ] && sed -i "s/$vfind/$vreplace/g" "$ddir/$nbas"
    done
```

- `find` natural output order make that directories are always renamed before their children, so that it is safe to rename only the basename element
- all names may safely contain spaces
- only one `find` does the job at lower cost
- you save dependencies to js

Comment: Thank you. I will review and test your scripts.